# Is the limit of symplectic diffeomophisms a diffeomorphism?

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry

Suppose we have a sequence, { f_n }, of symplectic diffeomorphisms of R^{2n}  converging to a function f.  By f_n converging to f I mean:  f_n converges to f in C^k(B_r) for every r > 0, where B_r is the ball centered at the origin of radius r.  Suppose k > 0.

Question:  Is f is diffeomorphism?  Certainly, f is symplectic and hence a local diffeomorphism, and so my question is really: is f invertible?

Interestingly enough, this is not true if f_n is not symplectic (e.g. take f_n = x/n, which converges to 0 in C^k(B_r) for every r > 0).

Thanks!

Comment: Why doesn't your exactly same example work in the simplectic case? The map $f_n:x\in\mathbb R^{2n}\mapsto x/n\in\mathbb R^{2n}$ is quite symplectic.

Comment: The fact that $\operatorname{SP}_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$ is closed in $M_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$ but $\operatorname{GL}_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$ is not seems relevant here.  

Comment: @Mariano: it is only a symplectomorphism if you take the source and target with differently scaled symplectic structure, no? So it is not really a symplectic automorphism, which is presumeably what the OP wants. 

Comment: Willie is correct in saying that I'd like each f_n to be a symplectic automorphism.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, $f$ doesn't have to be invertible.  It has to be injective, even in the volume-preserving category rather than the symplectic category.  None of the singular values of $Df$ can go to 0, because some other singular value would go to $\infty$.  This shows that it is locally injective, and then globally it is not possible to make the locally injective pieces overlap.

But even when $n=1$, it does not have to be surjective.  In this case the symplectic condition says just that $f_n$ is area-preserving.  You can reshape larger and larger circles centered at $0$ to non-concentric circles with the same area that lie in the upper half plane.  So the image of $f$ could be the upper half plane.  Actually, I think that the image of $f$ can be any open topological disk with infinite area.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I thought about whether the image of f can be the upper half plane, but wasn't sure.

Are you 100% sure that this example works?  I tried to construct f_n somewhat more explicitly, but had some trouble. In the examples I try to come up with the f_n's do not converge (e.g. my first naive attempt to explicitly carry out your example was to take f_n(x,y) = (x, y + n)).

Do you know any conditions that one can give on f_n to guarantee that f is invertible? 

Comment: It's a bit tricky to write explicit formulas, but yeah, I'm fairly sure.  You can even make $f_n = f$ on the disk $B_n(0)$.  Maybe the trick is to make $f$ first, so that it takes circles at the origin to circles in the upper half plane, and then change it outside of a disk of radius $n$ to make $f_n$.


Answer (score 0):

To find explicit examples of what Greg Kuperberg suggests, maybe one can try the following. Consider $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ as the cotangent bundle of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then diffeomorphisms between opens subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ lift to symplectomorphisms of the "cylinders" over these open subsets. So you can find a sequence of diffeomorphisms of $\mathbb{R}^n$ converging to a diffeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^n$ onto a proper open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. When $n =1$ you can take a sequence converging to $f(x) = e^x$ (for instance $f_n(x) = e^x + \frac{x}{n}$). The symplectomorphisms obtained as the lift of these maps should give you an example of what Greg Kuperberg suggested.